# How to serve images added via user in Django in deployment

Tags: python, django, apache, e-commerce

I have a Django E-commerce App on the cloud. I have configured to add products and images from admin. It was working fine in the development server but doesnt work in deployement. I cant find any good answers anywhere, google seems to be filled with resources about serving static files. Some answers are that apache would be required but i use nginx so how would that work. Help would be appreciated..

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    description = models.TextField(default='' , null=True , blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/products/')
    old_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=299)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/suits/', null=True, blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/suits/', null=True, blank=True)

    tags= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True))
```

settings.py config

```
MEDIA_URL = "/image/download/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Django does not serve media files in production (inefficient). See [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/) for steps to do that in production.

Comment: I followed this, but it didn't work.  Below is my configuration for running collectstatic                              STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "/uploads/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')